# How to rewrite a request to different files based on the domain name in ".htaccess"?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I run the website `https://www.1.example`. The contents of my `.htaccess` file are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \city.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I would like to connect the second domain `https://2.example` to this site. How to modify the `.htaccess` file so that it redirects the query to the appropriate file due the domain used by the visitor. My point is that when someone enters my website from the domain `https://1.example` or `https://www.1.example`, he should be redirected to the file `city.php?q=` and when he enters from the domain `https://2.example` or `https://www.2.example` to the file `file2.php?q=`.

Comment: What do you want to happen when requesting the document root (homepage)? Unless `city.php` is defined as the `DirectoryIndex` then you currently have another file that is handling such requests?

Comment: As @MrWhite alludes, while this can be done, why would you want to use city.php rather than index.php which is usually the default file that is opened?

Comment: @Steve (/Bartosz) It's perfectly reasonable to use a filename other than `index.php` for this, particularly in this case when there are two files (two "front-controllers"). I'm simply querying what is expected/currently happening for root requests, which is not clear from the question - the current directives do not handle this case (and I assume the current config is working as expected for one domain). Without more information then we would need to "guess" what the intention is.

Comment: OK, I already explain everything. The redirection in the `.htaccess` file is used to make the site more "SEO-friendly". Instead of referring to `www.1.example/city.php?q=blah_blah_blah`, just enter `www.1.example/blah_blah_blah`
I am going to launch a second site that will be very similar in content to the first site but will have a slightly different function. This second site, `www.2.example`, is to use the same resources as the first site, `www.1.example`, and is to be in the same folder on the server's disk.

Comment: "I already explain everything." - Well, actually you've not. You've not addressed the question in my first comment... how are requests for the root directory (ie. the homepage) currently handled? The directives you've posted in the question do not handle such a request, so either you have other directives or another file (eg. `index.php`) that handles this request? This is relevant as it determines how the directives should be written and how requests for the root directory of the _second domain_ should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

You've not stated how you are currently handling requests for the root directory (homepage), as this is not handled by the directives you have posted (since the second *condition* explicitly excludes all directories). However, I'll assume that all requests for the first domain are being handled correctly by the existing rule (and server config) and any requests for the second domain (including the root directory) should be sent to `file2.php`.

A couple of asides...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \city.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

The backslash-escape at the start of the *substitution* string looks like an error/typo. There is no need to escape a literal `c` here. You probably meant to use a (forward) slash (ie. `/`), but this is not required either (and best omitted).

Minor point, but the start-of-string (`^`) and end-of-string (`$`) anchors on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^(.*)$` are not required since regex is greedy by default.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> ```

Do you need to make an exception for requests that map to physical directories? Do you need to be able to access directories themselves? Although you see this a lot, it's actually very rare that this would be required. Without this, your rules can be simpler and more efficient.

The presence of this *condition* will often mean that a request for a directory would result in a "403 Forbidden". Whereas, without this *condition* the request would be routed through your front-controller, which would probably result in a "404 Not Found" (which is often preferable).

### Solution

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

# (Optional) Abort early if either front-controller already reached
RewriteRule ^(city|file2)\.php$ - [L]

# If the request matches the first domain then skip the next 2 rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?1\.example [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [S=2]

# Second domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) file2.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]

# Second domain root directory (homepage)
RewriteRule ^$ file2.php [L]

# First domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) city.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note that I also changed the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `.*` to `.+` which avoids an unnecessary filesystem check for requests to the document root.

There is also an additional question to ponder... what do you want to happen if the front-controller (ie. `city.php` or `file2.php`) is requested directly? Allow it? Block it? Redirect it?